# using input() for custom command

Tags: vimscript

I'm using vim to edit my latex files and I'm trying to automate some aspects of it.

I want a command that inserts the following:

```latex
\begin{env}

\end{env}
```

Where `env` is an user input. So I came up whit this

```
function Begin()
   call inputsave()
   let env = input("env = ")
   call inputrestore()
   execute "normal! i\begin{" . a:env . "}\n\n\end{" . a:env . "}<esc>k"
endfunction
```

The last part , `<esc>k`, is meant to put the cursor above the last line.

But unfortunaly I can make it work, it tells me `E121 a:env not defined`. I create a custom command to call the function

```
nnoremap ,b :call Begin()<CR>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two problems:

1. Don't use`a:` for any local variables, as **Luc Hermitte** pointed out.
2. When using the command `execute` you should use [|expr-string|](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr-string) and to insert `\` it should be `\\`.

And so, the right way of writing it is like this

```
function! Begin()
   call inputsave()
   let env = input("env: ")
   call inputrestore()
   execute "normal! i\\begin{".env."}\n\n\\end{".env."}\<ESC>o
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

`a:` is for arguments. Don't use any prefix for local variables.

PS: you'll have a better experience with a single new line and `O` instead of `k`

Comment: Removing ```a:``` did work but also ```\begin...``` and ```\end{...``` are wrong. It has to be ```\\begin...``` and ```\\end...```